# C++ variable change monitor

Tags: c++, debugging

For debugging purposes, I would like to find a way how to automatically keep track of the changes of the variables involved in my design.

The result I would like to obtain is like the printf of the new value every time the variable is assigned, but without manually inserting all the printf.

What is the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: The debugger can do that. Do you need it to be done in code?

Comment: Otherwise (if not the debugger method) you'd either need to make sure you used accessors, or wrap all variables so that operator= , copies and other methods of assignment triggered some output.

Comment: Please say what IDE are you using? I know a few ways to do it in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8):

Create a new class for the variables you want to monitor and define an appropriate `operator=` assignment operator method:

```
template <class T>
class MonitoredVariable
{
public:
    MonitoredVariable() {}
    MonitoredVariable(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}

    T operator T() const { return m_value; }

    const MonitoredVariable& operator = (const T& value)
    {
        printf("Variable modified\n");
        m_value = value;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    T m_value;
}
```

Example usage:

```
MoniredVariable<int> x;
x = 42;  // Will print "Variable modified"
```

Of course, for this to be useful, you'll have to include relevant information in the `operator=` implementation, and you'll also have to overload the other arithmetic assignment operators such as `+=`, `-=`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write some proxy class for them and redefine assignment operator.
It colud have pointer or value semantic, but I would prefer pointer, because it's simple.

```
template<class T>
struct proxy
{
//add const version
  T & operator * ()
  {
    std::cout << "access" << std::endl;
    return val_;
  }

  T * operator -> ()
  {
    std::cout << "access" << std::endl;
    return &val_;
  }

  proxy<T> & operator = (T const & other)
  {
    std::cout << "access" << std::endl;
    val = other;
    return (*this);
  }
private:
   T val_;
};
```

Comment: This has mixed semantics. If you write `proxy<int> i;` then `i = 12` and `*i = 12` have the same effect.

Comment: yep, but that is the way it should be. *i = x; does assignment behind proxy =)

Answer (score 0):

[WaitOnAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress)

```
ULONG g_TargetValue; // global, accessible to all threads
ULONG CapturedValue;
ULONG UndesiredValue;

UndesiredValue = 0;
CapturedValue = g_TargetValue;
while (CapturedValue == UndesiredValue) {
      WaitOnAddress(&g_TargetValue, &UndesiredValue, sizeof(ULONG), INFINITE);
      CapturedValue = g_TargetValue;
}
```

You have to create a thread to wait for g_TargetValue being changed by another thread.